# How to a add a list of items into the sqlite3 flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, blueprint

I've recently started with blueprint flask.
There is a list of dicts => list[{'title':'ajsdhkd', 'author': 'askjdh qweqwqw'}, {'title':'ajsdhkd', 'author': 'askjdh qweqwqw'}] that I need to add to sql.
I want to initialize my database with created table that will contain this dicts.  So that I can later execute it from blueprint flask route.
But I don't understand how can it be done.

In db.py I have created :

```
import sqlite3
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext


def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db

def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
    
def close_db(e=None): 
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))


@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

There is a schema.sql file where:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books;

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    title varchar(50),
    author varchar(100),

);
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

Using plain sqlite3, the below function should create a SQLite table named "books" and then add the list of dicts you describe to that table.  You may want to substitute `current_app.config['DATABASE']` in place of `'test.db'`.

```py
import sqlite3

def init_db():
    data = [{'title':'ajsdhkd', 'author': 'askjdh qweqwqw'}, {'title':'ajsdhkd', 'author': 'askjdh qweqwqw'}]

    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE 'books' (title TEXT, author TEXT);")    

    sql = "INSERT INTO 'books' (title, author) VALUES (?, ?);"
    for book in data:
        cursor.execute(sql, (book['title'], book['author']))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

You may also consider this alternative that uses my "easy_db" library to simplify building the "books" table and adding data to it.  This function does the same thing as the previous function.

```py
import easy_db

def init_db2():    
    data = [{'title':'ajsdhkd', 'author': 'askjdh qweqwqw'}, {'title':'ajsdhkd', 'author': 'askjdh qweqwqw'}]
    
    db = easy_db.DataBase('test.db')    
    db.append('books', data)
```

The single `db.append('books', data)` line both creates the "books" table and adds the `data` list of dicts to that table.  The "title" and "author" columns are automatically created with the TEXT type based on the input data.